# TestNG is not listing under preference or under library even after installing testNG form the Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin, testng

i have installed testNG from Eclipse Marketplace and after restarting i'm not able to locate testNG under library or under project preference.
When i tried to install it again it says testNG is already installed.
I have tried uninstalling testNG and installing from "http://beust.com/eclipse" and i'm still facing the same problem.
Eclipse i'm using is JUNO.

Regards
John

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Navigate to: Java Build path > Add Library > And add TestNG

Comment: I have tried this too, still I'm not able to locate TestNG.

Comment: Look into this: http://goo.gl/jVyj3r, you can add testng jar and if you are downloading from eclipse, make sure to install the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart eclipse after testng jar is installed.